# How do I run RDD operations after a groupby in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I have a large set of data that I want to perform clustering on. The catch is, I don't want one clustering for the whole set, but a clustering for each user. Essentially I would do a groupby userid first, then run KMeans.

The problem is, once you do a groupby, any mapping would be outside the spark controller context, so any attempt to create RDDs would fail. Spark's KMeans lib in mllib requires an RDD (so it can parallelize).

I see two workarounds, but I was hoping there was a better solution.

1) Manually loop through all the thousands of users in the controller (maybe millions when things get big), and run kmeans for each of them.

2) Do the groupby in the controller, then in map run a non-parallel kmeans provided by an external library.

Please tell me there is another way, I'd rather just have everything || as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit: I didn't know it was `pyspark` at the moment of the response. However, I will leave it as an idea that may be adapted*

I had a similar problem and I was able to improve the performance, but it was still not the ideal solution for me. Maybe for you it could work.

The idea was to break the RDD in many smaller RDDs (a new one for each user id), saving them to an array, then calling the processing function (clustering in your case) for each "sub-RDD". The suggested code is given below (explanation in the comments):

```scala
// A case class just to use as example
case class MyClass(userId: Long, value: Long, ...)

// A Scala local array with the user IDs (Could be another iterator, such as List or Array):
val userList: Seq[Long] = rdd.map{ _.userId }.distinct.collect.toSeq  // Just a suggestion!

// Now we can create the new rdds:
val rddsList: Seq[RDD[MyClass]] = userList.map { 
  userId => rdd.filter({ item: MyClass => item.userId == userId }) 
}.toSeq

// Finally, we call the function we want for each RDD, saving the results in a new list. 
// Note the ".par" call, which is used to start the expensive execution for multiple RDDs at the same time
val results = rddsList.par.map {
  r => myFunction(r)
}
```

I know this is roughly the same as your first option, but by using the `.par` call, I was able to improve the performance.

This call transforms the `rddsList` object to a [`ParSeq`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParSeq) object. This new Scala object allows parallel computation, so, ideally, the map function will call `myFunction(r)` for multiple RDDs at once, which can improve the performance.

For more details about parallel collections, please check the [Scala Documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html).

Comment: what is the type of userList? array? I'm trying to find the 'par' method

Comment: userList is a Scala local iterator (Array, List, Seq, ...)

Comment: Hmm, so is par part of the Spark api? How is it attached to a native Scala type?
Closest thing I can find in the docs is var rdd = sc.parallelize(data); which doesn't do the same thing you say here. Can you point to a doc page about this?

Comment: I added the link to the response. The `par` is a Scala method which is available for the main Scala collections. In my example, I call it to an array of RDDs, created by filtering the main RDD many times.

Comment: I feel like filtering over and over can't possibly be as performant as a groupby, but thanks for the help.

Comment: If you are using the RDD's groupBy, it can be really inefficient, as can be seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977182/spark-groupby-taking-lot-of-time), [here](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html) and in the Spark's documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD), so maybe you could give my solution a go.

Comment: So par only distributes across processes on one machine, not multiple machines over the network. So realistically this would only help if the controller machine had many processors. Is that right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111481/discussion-between-daniel-de-paula-and-nathaniel-tucker).

Comment: I was able to do a similar version of this in pyspark by using this API: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/concurrent.futures.html to || my map